# Putting MYSQL results into PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem with the retrieval of data in a mysql database into a php array. If I execute the code below, the query fetches some corresponding rows twice or even 3 times.
I got a database of files listed with the name and the date of the upload.
Let's say I have 4 files (This was tested):
File1, File2, File3, File4.
The code would echo (if it helps):

```
File1 and its date
File1 and its date
File4 and its date
File2 and its date
File2 and its date
File3 and its date
File3 and its date
File4 and its date
File4 and its date
```

Here is the code:

```
$query = $pdo_con->query("SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE  active = 1 and owner = '$current_user' Order By upload_id DESC");

while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $new_array[] = $r;
    $new_array[$r['name']] = $r;
    $new_array[$r['uploaded']] = $r;
}
foreach($new_array as $array){
    echo $array['name'];
    echo $array['uploaded'];
}
```

I would like to have the code echo each file only once and in the correct order (descending order of upload_id(auto incrementing))

Comment: You are adding the `$row` multiple times to the `$new_array`. 3 times for each row. If you are expecting it to show up once, then only add it once. Also, pdo does have a `fetchAll` method that gets all rows into an array.

Comment: If you run the query do you see multiple rows in the results? If you are not doing anything with `$new_array` why not just echo in place or use `fetchAll()` and loop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are creating your array is giving you 3 elements each time through the loop.  Try:

```
$i;
while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $new_array[$i][$r['name']] = $r['name'];
    $new_array[$i][$r['uploaded']] = $r['uploaded'];
    $i++;
}
```

However, if you specify the columns in your query it's much easier:

```
SELECT name, uploaded FROM uploads
    WHERE  active = 1 AND owner = '$current_user'
    ORDER BY upload_id DESC
```

Then:

```
$new_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Alternately, if you don't need the `$new_array` but only want to display:

```
while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $r['name'];
    echo $r['uploaded'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your second option fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$query = $pdo_con->query("SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE  active = 1 and owner = '$current_user' Order By upload_id DESC");

while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $r['name'];
    echo $r['uploaded'];
}
```

Or:

```
$query = $pdo_con->query("SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE  active = 1 and owner = '$current_user' Order By upload_id DESC");

while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $new_array[] = ['name'=>$r['name'], 'uploaded'=>$r['uploaded']];
}
foreach($new_array as $array){
    echo $array['name'];
    echo $array['uploaded'];
}
```